# Como evitar que um Checkbox receba eventos de clique?

Tags: java, android

Quero criar uma lista onde cada item possua um checkbox puramente informativo, para que quando o usuário acessar este item, o checkbox passe a ser marcado. Mas após uma implementação de teste, pude notar que quando utilizo o checkbox, o sistema não executa o `OnItemClick`. Se eu remover o checkbox, o sistema executa o `OnItemClick`.
Eu preciso fazer alguma coisa?

Minha Lista:

```
public class ListaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private ListView listView;

private AdapterListView adapterListView;

private ArrayList<ItemListView> Itens;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstLista);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    CriarLista();
}

// Adiciona item por item da lista e o que se quer nela
private void CriarLista(){

    Itens = new ArrayList<ItemListView>();

    ItemListView Item1 = new ItemListView("Frase 1", 0);
    ItemListView Item2 = new ItemListView("Frase 2", 0);
    ItemListView Item3 = new ItemListView("Frase 3", 0);
    ItemListView Item4 = new ItemListView("Frase 4", 0);
    ItemListView Item5 = new ItemListView("Frase 5!", 0);

    Itens.add(Item1);
    Itens.add(Item2);
    Itens.add(Item3);
    Itens.add(Item4);
    Itens.add(Item5);

    adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, Itens);

    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);

    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}

// O que deve acontecer quando clicar em um item
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
    ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(arg2);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item Selecionado: " + item.getTexto(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Meu itemListView:

```
public class ItemListView {
private String Texto;
private int Check; //0- Desabilitado 1-Habilitado

public ItemListView(String texto, int check){
    this.Texto = texto;
    this.Check = check;
}

public String getTexto(){
    return Texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto){
    Texto = texto;
}

public int getCheck(){
    return Check;
}

public void setCheck(int check){
    Check = check;
}
```

E o AdapterListView:

```
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> Itens;

public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListView> Itens){
    this.Itens = Itens;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount(){
    return Itens.size();
}

public ItemListView getItem(int position){
    return Itens.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    ItemListView item = Itens.get(position);
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, null);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtItem)).setText(item.getTexto());
    ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkItem)).setChecked(false);
    return view;
}
```

Note que foi implementado para que caso o usuário selecione um item da lista, o sistema apresentar um `Toast` indicando qual item foi selecionado. Porém, o sistema não está realizando esta ação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível resolver isso colocando

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

no checkbox que vai ser somente informativo pelo XML.

Se precisar algum dia que o checkbox tenha um evento de click também, ai tem que usar o padrão ViewHolder. Recomendo também uma leitura já e migrar para RecyclerView com ViewHolder, vai resolver muitos dos problemas.